# Generate Date from System.nanoTime()

Tags: java, date

I am writing a code for implementing Stop Watch. I capture a moment with `System.nanoTime()`. But I would also like to convert and store that moment into a date field. When I try to use `new Date(long msec)`, it's giving me some absurd date-time value. Can anyone help me how to get this done?

Comment: nanotime is not the current time. Use `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: Can you post code + example of what you get (before and after the conversion)? Have you also tried something like [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2012/12/how-to-convert-millisecond-to-date-in-java-example.html) (note that it handles milliseconds but you can easily apply this to nanoseconds)?

Comment: @ReutSharabani Yeah, that's right. I posted a link to an example.

Comment: But can we not able to dynamically find Date from a nanotime? What is the 0th nanosec means then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`System.nanoTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) is not the current time:

> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time.

This is why you're experiencing "some absurd date-time value".

Use [`System.currentTimeMillis`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) if you want the date(s) you've captured as milliseconds (see: [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)):

> the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all.. got the ans.. so now I am doing like this -- 
long curMilSec = System.currentTimeMillis();
long nanSec = System.nanoTime();
long  startMillis = curMilSec-(nanSec/1000000);
.......
new Date(System.nanotime()/ 1000000 + startMillis);